# Call a router WITHIN Nodejs after a route has been called

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, auth0

I am using Expressjs and the Auth0 API for authentication and ReactJs for client side.
Because of the limitations of the Auth0 API (spoke with their team) I am sending updated user details to my backend and then using `app.set()` to be able to use the req.body in another route.
I need to call the app.patch() route automatically after the app.post() route has been hit.
The end goal is that the users data will be updated and shown client side.

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config()
const { auth } = require("express-openid-connect");


app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.use(
  auth({
    issuerBaseURL: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL,
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    authRequired: false,
    auth0Logout: true,
  })
);


app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
  
});


app.get('/api', async (req, res) => {

  const stripe = require('stripe')(`${process.env.REACT_APP_Stripe_Live}`);
  const invoice = await stripe.invoices.list({
    limit: 3,
  });
  res.json(invoice);
});

app.post('/updateuser', (req, ) => {
   app.set('data', req.body);
  })
 
app.patch(`https://${process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL}/api/v2/users/:id`,(req,res) => {
  let val = app.get('data');
 req.params =  {id: val.id};
  console.log(req.params);
}) 



app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on 8080`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you just take the code from inside of `app.patch()` and make it into a reusable function.  Then it can be called from either the `app.patch()` route directly or from your other route that wants to do the same funtionality.  Just decide what interface for that function will work for both, make it a separate function and then you can call it from both places.

For some reason (which I don't really understand, but seems to happen to lots of people), people forget that the code inside of routes can also be put into functions and shared just like any other Javascript code.  I guess people seems to think of a route as a fixed unit by itself and forget that it can still be broken down into components and those components shared with other code.

---

**Warning.**  On another point.  This comment of yours sounds very wrong:

> and then using app.set() to be able to use the req.body in another route

`req.body` belongs to one particular user.  `app.set()` is global to your server (all user's requests access it).  So, you're trying to store temporary state for one single user in essentially a global.  That means that multiple user's request that happen to be in the process of doing something similar will trounce/overwrite each other's data.  Or worse, one user's data will accidentally become some other user's data.  You cannot program a multi-user server this way at all.

The usual way around this is to either 1) redesign the process so you don't have to save state on the server (stateless operations are generally better, if possible) or 2) Use a user-specific session (like with `express-session`) and save the temporary state in the user's session.  Then, it is saved separately for each user and one user's state won't overwrite anothers.

If this usage of `app.set()` was to solve the original problem of executing a `.patch()` route, then the problem is solved by just calling a shared function and passing the `req.body` data directly to that shared function.  Then, you don't have to stuff it away somewhere so a later route can use it.  You just execute the functionality you want and pass it the desired data.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer. I should clarify this is just a minimal viable product for myself so I am focused on getting it to work then going back and refractoring. I say this because expression-session is something  I will be implementing. If I am understanding correctly I can just have the app.patch() and inside the route call a function that handles what I want?

Comment: @AS10 - Yes, you can have both routes just call the same function and have each route pass the appropriate data to the shared function as arguments.  I wouldn't implement an MVP that could only work for one user.  There are appropriate shortcuts for an MVP, but doing something that would only work for one user is going a bit far as you generally expect multiple users to be able to use an MVP so you can get early feedback.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I will implement express-sessions now then and creat a shared function.

Comment: @AS10 - If I understood things correctly, this problem can probably be solved purely with a shared function without express-session.  You will likely want express-session for other things though.

Comment: I will most likely need to use it because I sent data to one end point and I need to pass it to another endpoint.

Comment: @AS10 - Perhaps you didn't understand my suggestion.  Rather than executing an http request for the second endpoint from the first endpoint, you just let the first endpoint gather the data it wants to send the second endpoint and call a shared function that contains the functionality of the second endpoint and pass it the data you've already gathered as arguments (regular function call, no session used).  You don't need to squirrel the data away in the session and then actually do an http request for the second endpoint.

Comment: I appreciate the explaination. Thats what I am using now, thank you!